# Defining variable to be used in few places

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a functionality in Tabluau to create a variable that can be used in few places by referring to its name? I'm asking because I need to prepare a dashboard and the data loaded and displayed on the dashboard can contain two different variables in column called `value`. So I would need to define such a 'variable' that would be filled with the type of `value` column (ex. `type 1` or `type 2`) and use it as a axis name, in a tooltip etc. Of course, I'm trying to avoid a necessity to change all the axis names and tooltips manually.

Answer (score 2):

In Tableau, they are called parameters. Please refer to following articles to learn more about this.

1. [Parameter basics](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm)
2. [Swapping Measures using parameter](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_swap.htm)

I believe what you are asking is covered in link 2.